# How to add test onto each bar?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, facet-wrap

I am trying to add text onto each bar, can someone please help me show how I can do? I am not a R user so please excuse my abilities. I appreciate your help. I got few responses earlier, like to use `annotate` or `geomtext` but i am not sure how to run them.
Here is my code:

```
library(viridis)
library(hrbrthemes)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(
  H1 = c(6.36, 3.03, 6.85, 4.07, 4.69, 6.27, 6.67, 3.11, 5.07, 6.14, 5.93, 6.49),
  H2 = c(5.15, 5.00, 5.71, 5.50, 4.99, 5.81, 6.05, 5.76, 5.28, 5.69, 5.69, 5.06),
  H3 = c(3.85, 5.13, 4.99, 4.91, 5.01, 5.73, 5.77, 5.94, 5.57, 5.35, 6.00, 4.39),
  H4 = c(3.84, 4.80, 5.15, 4.85, 4.99, 5.73, 5.77, 5.45, 5.44, 5.41, 5.81, 4.46),
  H5 = c(4.08, 5.17, 4.77, 5.03, 5.00, 5.49, 5.49, 5.80, 5.51, 5.18, 5.76, 4.60),
  H6 = c(4.35, 5.59, 5.59, 4.83, 5.52, 5.63, 5.85, 5.74, 5.66, 5.19, 5.79, 4.84), fontface = c("bold"),
  names = c("RB", "Ver", "Atl", "POR12PG28-3",
            "Valery", "Rio", "CO99076-6R", "Purple",
            "AC99330-1P/Y", "CO05068-1RU", "Masquerade", "Canela"),
  specie = c(rep("Appearance", 12), rep("Aroma" , 12), rep("Flavor" , 12),
             rep("Overall" , 12), rep("Aftertaste", 12), rep("Texture", 12)),
  condition = rep(c("RB", "Ver", "Atl", "POR12PG28-3",
                    "Valery", "Rio", "CO99076-6R", "Purple",
                    "AC99330-1P/Y", "CO05068-1RU", "Masquerade", "Canela") , 6))

df <- df %>%
  pivot_longer(starts_with("H"), names_to = "h.names")
df

#one condition per plot
nameframe <- enframe(unique(df$h.names))
specieframe <- enframe(unique(df$specie))
names.labs <- c("Appearance", "Aroma", "Flavor", "Overall", "Aftertaste", "Texture")
names(names.labs) <- c("H1", "H2", "H3", "H4", "H5", "H6")

ggplot() +
  geom_col(data = df, mapping = aes(x = names, y = value), 
           position = "dodge") +
  coord_flip() +
  ylim(c(0,9)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0.0, 9, 3), limits=c(0, 9), labels = c("0", "3", "6", "Like\nExtremely")) +
  labs(y = "", x = "") + theme(legend.title = element_blank(), axis.text.y = element_text(face = "bold", size = 11),
                               axis.text.x = element_text(face = "bold", size = 9)) +
  scale_fill_discrete(breaks = c("Appearance", "Aroma", "Flavor", "Overall", "Aftertaste", "Texture")) +
  facet_wrap(~h.names, labeller = labeller(h.names = names.labs))


#add text onto each bar
p <- p + annotate("text", label = "Test", size = 4, x = 15, y = 5)
print(p)
text(x = H,
     y = y,
     labels = c("ab", "e", "a", "d", "cd", "ab", "ab", "e", "c", "ab", "b", "ab"),
     pos = 2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you would add the text you had in your original question to each bar. Please note that I moved `data = df, mapping = aes(x = names, y = value` up into the `ggplot()` aesthetic where it will be applied to each layer in the plot. Next, used `case_when` from the `dplyr` package to add the bar plot labels as a new column to `df`. After that you pass in the new column into `geom_text` like so `geom_text(aes(label = bar_labels, hjust = 0))` to apply the labels on the tip of each bar.

```r
library(viridis)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(
  H1 = c(6.36, 3.03, 6.85, 4.07, 4.69, 6.27, 6.67, 3.11, 5.07, 6.14, 5.93, 6.49),
  H2 = c(5.15, 5.00, 5.71, 5.50, 4.99, 5.81, 6.05, 5.76, 5.28, 5.69, 5.69, 5.06),
  H3 = c(3.85, 5.13, 4.99, 4.91, 5.01, 5.73, 5.77, 5.94, 5.57, 5.35, 6.00, 4.39),
  H4 = c(3.84, 4.80, 5.15, 4.85, 4.99, 5.73, 5.77, 5.45, 5.44, 5.41, 5.81, 4.46),
  H5 = c(4.08, 5.17, 4.77, 5.03, 5.00, 5.49, 5.49, 5.80, 5.51, 5.18, 5.76, 4.60),
  H6 = c(4.35, 5.59, 5.59, 4.83, 5.52, 5.63, 5.85, 5.74, 5.66, 5.19, 5.79, 4.84), fontface = c("bold"),
  names = c("RB", "Ver", "Atl", "POR12PG28-3",
            "Valery", "Rio", "CO99076-6R", "Purple",
            "AC99330-1P/Y", "CO05068-1RU", "Masquerade", "Canela"),
  specie = c(rep("Appearance", 12), rep("Aroma" , 12), rep("Flavor" , 12),
             rep("Overall" , 12), rep("Aftertaste", 12), rep("Texture", 12)),
  condition = rep(c("RB", "Ver", "Atl", "POR12PG28-3",
                    "Valery", "Rio", "CO99076-6R", "Purple",
                    "AC99330-1P/Y", "CO05068-1RU", "Masquerade", "Canela") , 6))

df <- df %>%
  pivot_longer(starts_with("H"), names_to = "h.names")


#one condition per plot
nameframe <- enframe(unique(df$h.names))
specieframe <- enframe(unique(df$specie))
names.labs <- c("Appearance", "Aroma", "Flavor", "Overall", "Aftertaste", "Texture")
names(names.labs) <- c("H1", "H2", "H3", "H4", "H5", "H6")


#add text onto each bar
df <- df %>% 
  arrange(desc(names)) %>% 
  group_by(names) %>% 
  mutate(
    bar_labels = case_when(
      names == "Ver" ~ "ab",
      names == "Valery" ~ "e",
      names == "Rio" ~ "a",
      names == "RB" ~ "d",
      names == "Purple" ~ "cd",
      names == "POR12PG28-3" ~ "ab",
      names ==  "Masquerade" ~ "ab",
      names == "CO99076-6R" ~ "e",
      names == "CO05068-1RU" ~ "c",
      names == "Canela" ~ "ab",
      names == "Atl" ~ "b",
      names == "AC99330-1P/Y" ~ "ab",
      TRUE ~ as.character(NA)
    ))

ggplot(data = df, mapping = aes(x = names, y = value)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge") +
  coord_flip() +
  ylim(c(0,9)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0.0, 9, 3), limits=c(0, 9), labels = c("0", "3", "6", "Like\nExtremely")) +
  labs(y = "", x = "") + theme(legend.title = element_blank(), axis.text.y = element_text(face = "bold", size = 11),
                               axis.text.x = element_text(face = "bold", size = 9)) +
  scale_fill_discrete(breaks = c("Appearance", "Aroma", "Flavor", "Overall", "Aftertaste", "Texture")) +
  facet_wrap(~h.names, labeller = labeller(h.names = names.labs)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = bar_labels, hjust = 0))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-03-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the help. Let me absorb what you stated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: How I can add specific text under each category? Like, now they have same for all samples, like Ver - ab in all barplots. Likewise Atl - b in all plots?

Comment: Take this solution and create another question on StackOverflow. Best practice is not to continue to add on to already answered solutions with new questions in the comments. Rather, the asker should ask a new question in addition to the one that was already answered since they are technically two separate questions thus preserving the information captured already.